# Bind two properties on target to single source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm developing a Maze with WPF and C# where I put an Agent at a random position inside the Maze and the GUI shows the process of finding the exit using a search algorithm.

I first divide the Grid on rows and columns, then I add a rectangle on each grid/row pair and finally I add an extra rectangle to the grid that represents my Agent.

I want to bind the position of the agent Rectangle in the Grid to an Agent class property that represents its position with a Point class.

As I'm fairly new to these technologies I looked on the Web and came with the current solution:

Creating a new rectangle class wich I call ExtendedRectangle and within it create a custom DependencyProperty that gives me control to a Grid.RowProperty and Grid.ColumnProperty via a Point.

The problem is that debugging code and setting breakpoints on my setters and getters, it seems the breakpoints are not reached during execution using setValue() methods but they are being called when I modify its value explicitly. Furthermore I change the position of the Agents rectangle at runtime and I see the value is getting updated but my GUI isn't.

I would like some enlightenment on this or a better approach. Thanks.

This is how I do the binding on my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Maze maze = new Maze(15, 15);
        TimerCallback callback; //
        Timer stateTimer; //
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = maze;
            DrawMap(15, 15);
            callback = new TimerCallback(Update); //
            stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 2000, 2000); //
        }

        public void DrawMap(int ancho, int alto)
        {
            /********ADD COLUMNS, ROWS AND RECTANGLES CODE WAS HERE*************/
            // commented code are my tests

            ExtendedRectangle agent = new ExtendedRectangle();
            agent.BaseRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
            //agent.GridPosition = new Point(5, 5);
            //Console.WriteLine(agent.GridPosition.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine(maze.GetAgent().Position.ToString());
            agent.SetValue(ExtendedRectangle.GridPositionProperty, maze.GetAgent().Position);
            //Console.WriteLine(agent.GridPosition.ToString());
            Binding bind = new Binding("Position") { Source = maze.GetAgent() };
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            //bind.Converter = new AgentToGridPosition();
            agent.SetBinding(ExtendedRectangle.GridPositionProperty, bind);
            Mapa.Children.Add(agent.BaseRectangle);
        }

        public void Update(Object stateInfo) //
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int x = r.Next(0, 14);
            int y = r.Next(0, 14);
            Point p = new Point(x, y);

            maze.GetAgent().Position = p;
            Console.WriteLine("UPDATED POSITION:" + maze.GetAgent().Position.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And this is my ExtendedRectangle Class:

```
    class ExtendedRectangle
    {
        private Rectangle baseRectangle;
        private Point propertyType;

        public ExtendedRectangle()
        {
            baseRectangle = new Rectangle();
            propertyType = new Point();
        }

        public Rectangle BaseRectangle
        {
            get
            {
                return baseRectangle;
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "GridPosition", typeof(Point), typeof(ExtendedRectangle));

        public Point GridPosition 
        {
            get
            {
                propertyType.X = Convert.ToDouble(baseRectangle.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty));
                propertyType.Y = Convert.ToDouble(baseRectangle.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty));
                return propertyType;
            }
            set
            {
                propertyType = value;
                baseRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, (int)propertyType.X);
                baseRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, (int)propertyType.Y);
            }
        }

        public void SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, object value)
        {
            baseRectangle.SetValue(dp, value);
        }

        public BindingExpressionBase SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)
        {
            return baseRectangle.SetBinding(dp, binding);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `GridPosition` dependency property declaration is wrong. The CLR wrapper methods *must* call [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) and [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx), and they *should not* call anything else. See the [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN for all the details.

There is however no need at all for your `ExtendedRectangle` class. You could easily bind the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties on a regular Rectangle to a point property in your `Agent` class. Moreover, in order to simplify your bindinds your `Maze` class should have an `Agent` property instead of a `GetAgent` method.

In XAML it would look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    ...
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="{Binding Agent.Position.X}"
               Grid.Row="{Binding Agent.Position.Y}"
               Fill="LightGreen"/>
</Grid>
```

In code like this:

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.LightGreen };
rectangle.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding("Agent.Position.X"));
rectangle.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty, new Binding("Agent.Position.Y"));
grid.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

Please note that by means of the `Agent` property in class `Maze` you don't need to set the binding source explicitly, because the `Maze` instance is assigned to the MainWindow's `DataContext`.

Next thing is that if your bindings should be updated at runtime, you have to implement a property change notification mechanism in your `Agent` class. One way to do so is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface like this:

```
class Agent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Point position;
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set
        {
            position = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Position");
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I would recomment not to use `Point` as the type of the `Agent.Position` property, as its `X` and `Y` values are of type `double` (you already realized this). Better use some struct with integer `X` and `Y` values. Perhaps write your own one.

Comment: I dropped the custom `DependencyProperty` idea, implemented the bindings like you wrote and it Works now! :D However i still have a doubt on the CLR wrapper methods, you said it shouldn't call anything else tan `Get/SetValue()`...so if I wanted to return a `Point` from the Getter in my implementation, how could I do it since I need the two values to create one?

Comment: Please see the *Implementing the "Wrapper"* section in [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx#checklist) and also [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN for an explanation why the CLR wrapper methods should not call anything than GetValue and SetValue. Converting to another property type would be done by a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx).